# Seaborn Pairplot Graph inverts when saved as html using mpld3. how to fix it?

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, mpld3

I have created plot using Seaborn library in python

```
g = sns.PairGrid(df)
g = g.map_diag(plt.hist, edgecolor="w")
g = g.map_offdiag(plt.scatter, edgecolor="w")
g = g.add_legend()
```

[actual Graph before saving as html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUBDi.png)

using following line of code i converted it into html:

```
mpld3.save_html(g, path)
```

after saving as html each graph in it is inverted upside down as shown in figure below:

[Graph inverted When saved as html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s56Si.png)

how to fix it?

Comment: I doubt there is an easy fix to this. mpld3 is only capable of translating a subset of matplotlib properties and it seems it's not able to translate the hidden axes.